# Count length of JSON Object

Tags: json, angular, object, typescript

I have JSON which looks like this:

```
{
  "item1": {
    "category": "fruit",

  },
 "item2": {
    "category": "fruit",

  }
}
```

How can I count the no. of items inside this?

Comment: `Object.keys(...).length`?

Answer (score 1):

As in your JSON, number of items are the number of keys. Thus, get your JSON in an variable (say obj) and use the following:

```
var  obj = JSON.parse('{"item1":{"category":"fruit",},"item2":{"category":"fruit",}}');

Object.keys(obj).length;
```